# Windows phone 8.1 knownfolders issue with hidden files

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

When i try to fetch files from a KnownFolder(Example: KnownFolders.MusicLibrary) which has hidden files i see a UnauthorizedAccessException.

Is it a possibility to get sense hidden files by any chance from the KnownFolders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden files are not supported by the `StorageFile` APIs. They should not be enumerated by the `StorageFolder` APIs nor by the pickers. If you explicitly tried to open a file by name (because you already knew it existed) that is not a supported scenario (and in general you won't know what hidden files exist on other machines).

Comment: figured as much. Developer's hands tied again